# Magento 2 - How to get order id?

Tags: magento2, orders

following code:

```
<?php
namespace UV\Bestellung\Controller\Adminhtml\Order;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
class CreatePrint  extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order
{

    public function execute()
    {      


    /*
        $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
    */
        if($order->hasShipments()) {
            #Sendungen vorhanden
            $shipments = $order->getShipmentsCollection();
            $pdfGenerator = $objectManager->create('UV\Bestellung\Model\Order\Pdf\Shipment');
            $content = $pdfGenerator->getPdf($shipments);
            $fileFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory');
            $fileFactory->create('Bestellschein.pdf', $content->render(), DirectoryList::VAR_DIR , 'application/octet-stream'); 

        } else {
            #Keine Sendungen vorhanden
            print_r("Keine Sendung vorhanden!");
            exit;
        }
        // your logic here 
    }
}
?>
```

How can I get the order ID?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
namespace UV\Bestellung\Controller\Adminhtml\Order;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
class CreatePrint  extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order
{

    public function execute()
    {
        $order = $this->_initOrder();
        echo $order->getId();
        die;
         if($order->hasShipments()) {
            #Sendungen vorhanden
            $shipments = $order->getShipmentsCollection();
            $pdfGenerator = $objectManager->create('UV\Bestellung\Model\Order\Pdf\Shipment');
            $content = $pdfGenerator->getPdf($shipments);
            $fileFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory');
            $fileFactory->create('Bestellschein.pdf', $content->render(), DirectoryList::VAR_DIR , 'application/octet-stream'); 

        } else {
            #Keine Sendungen vorhanden
            print_r("Keine Sendung vorhanden!");
            exit;
        }
        // your logic here 
    }
}
```

**Used below code in your controller file for get order data:**

```
$order = $this->_initOrder();
echo $order->getId();
echo $order->getIncrementId();
```

**OR**

```
$orderId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
$order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
```

**OR**

```
$orderId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
$order =  $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
```